# How to delete some observations in some groups based on a condition

Tags: sql, sas

I would like delete some observations in some groups based on a condition.
My condition is each group : if (imput="toto") then delete
but if a whole group has imput="toto" then keep it

```
data temp;
input siren $ class $ imput $;
cards;
A CP titi
B CP toto
C CE tata
D CE tata
F CM toto
G CM toto
H SU tata
I SU toto
;
run;
```

The output I want :

```
siren class imput
A CP titi
C CE tata
D CE tata
F CM toto
G CM toto
H SU tata
```

Many thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to do two checks. Is the value toto and is the value only toto.  Here is SQL that will do that.  I had it explicitly create the checks as new variables so you can see what is happening. To see the check values for all observations remove the HAVING clause. If you are happy with it you can remove the check variables and just move the conditions into the having clause.

```
data temp;
  row+1;
  input siren $ class $ imput $;
cards;
A CP titi
B CP toto
C CE tata
D CE tata
F CM toto
G CM toto
H SU tata
I SU toto
;

proc sql ;
create table want as 
  select *
       , imput ne 'toto' as check1
       , max(imput ne 'toto') as check2
  from temp
  group by class 
  having check1 or not check2
  order by row
;
quit;
```

To do this with just a DATA step you will want add a "double DOW Loop" so you can calculate the overall flag for a group in the first loop and then process the individual rows in the second loop. Note this requires the input dataset is  sorted (or at least grouped) by class.

```
data want;
  do until(last.class);
    set temp;
    by class notsorted;
    if imput ne 'toto' then check2=1;
  end;
  do until(last.class);
    set temp;
    by class notsorted;
    if imput ne 'toto' or not check2 then output;
  end;
  drop check2;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL server you can achieve this through below query:

```
with cte as(
select * ,count(*) over(partition by class,input order by class,input)classwiseinputwisecount,
count(*) over(partition by class order by class )classwisecount
from data)
select * from data where not exists (
select siren,class,input from cte where classwiseinputwisecount<>classwisecount and input='toto' and cte.siren=data.siren)
```

Simplified version:

```
Proc SQL;
    select * from data where not exists (
    select siren,class,input from (
    select class,input ,count(*) classwiseinputwisecount,(select count(*) from data d where d.class=data.class)classwisecount
    
    from data
    group by class,input)cte
    where classwiseinputwisecount<>classwisecount and input='toto' and cte.class=data.class and cte.input=data.input);
    Quit;
```

result:
[image]

Comment: OVER and PARTITION are not supported in SAS SQL.

Comment: I just found out that. Let's try find some other aproach.

Comment: Thanks but I need a solution in SAS SQL

Comment: I have no knowledge of that but what i found out that it supports basic sql key words. let me find a simple solution and you can check.

Comment: I would be interested in the fastest way to achieve this result not using SQL but data steps...

Comment: Sorry to here that. These keywords are available in sas sql. But cant troublwshoot sys I don't have that platform. Best wishes

Comment: Thanks for you help !

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want :

```
;WITH a AS (SELECT class
FROM data
GROUP BY class
HAVING MAX(imput)<>MIN(imput) 
)
DELETE t FROM a JOIN data t ON t.class = a.class
WHERE t.imput='toto'
```

Comment: How would you write it in a PROC SQL ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with sas but the query is in the simplest and most basic form of sql language and you shouldn't have any trouble to use it in sas.

Comment: as you tagged 'sql' , it should be working for you.

Comment: Can you explain the logic of this code?  It does not look like it could work, but then the syntax of DELETE X FROM Y is foreign to me.

Comment: cte is supported in proc sql and you can use it as you want, this type of delete is called 'delete from query'

Comment: WITH is not supported in SAS SQL